# Extract year/month from a Pandas Timestamp column and store it in two new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` like this

```
                        DATE
0 2021-06-15 14:22:02.424126
1 2021-06-15 14:22:02.424126
```

I want new columns with the extracted `YEAR` and `MONTH`.

```
df['YEAR'] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: x.year)
df['MONTH'] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: x.month)
```

This gives me the expected result

```
                    DATE  YEAR  MONTH
0 2021-06-15 14:23:16.315543  2021      6
1 2021-06-15 14:23:16.315543  2021      6
```

But I want to do this in one line and one "iteration". I assume this would be faster.

```
# what I wish
df[['A', 'B']] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: (x.year, x.month))
```

But the result confuses me.

```
                        DATE  YEAR  MONTH     A     B
0 2021-06-15 14:23:16.315543  2021      6  2021  2021
1 2021-06-15 14:23:16.315543  2021      6     6     6
```

And I am not able to add a `axis=1` to `apply()`.

That is my full code

```
import pandas as pd

# That is the initial DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'DATE': [pd.Timestamp.now(),
                                   pd.Timestamp.now()]})

# works fine
df['YEAR'] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: x.year)
df['MONTH'] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: x.month)

# what I wish
df[['A', 'B']] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: (x.year, x.month))

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster is use native pandas functions, which are vectorized, not `apply` solutions (because apply are loops under the hood) with accessor [`.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) for apply function for `Series/ column`:

```
df['YEAR'] = df.DATE.dt.year
df['MONTH'] = df.DATE.dt.month
```

But it is possible by converting to list:

```
df[['A', 'B']] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: (x.year, x.month)).tolist()
```

---

```
# That is the initial DataFrame with 10k rows
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'DATE': [pd.Timestamp.now()] * 10000})


In [168]: %%timeit
     ...: df['YEAR'] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: x.year)
     ...: df['MONTH'] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: x.month)
     ...: 
     ...: 
70.4 ms ± 265 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [169]: %%timeit
     ...: df[['A', 'B']] = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: (x.year, x.month)).tolist()
     ...: 
     ...: 
64.5 ms ± 7.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [170]: %%timeit
     ...: df['C'] = df.DATE.dt.year
     ...: df['D'] = df.DATE.dt.month
     ...: 
     ...: 
2.34 ms ± 17.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Why the `.dt` in `df.Date.dt.year` ? When doing `apply()` with `x.year` there is no `.dt`.

Comment: @buhtz - there is difference, if use [dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) here [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html), it call function for column, if use `apply` is call function for Timestamp - here [`Timestamp.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.date.html) - there is no `dt`